# Knockout.js ToDo List

Tags: knockout.js, javascript, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-2.0

I am trying to create a simple ToDo list by loosely following the interactive tutorial on the Knockout site.

I can add an item to a list, but I can't remove it. What am I doing wrong ??

```
function ToDo(stuff) {
    this.toDoItem = stuff;
}

function ToDoViewModel() {

    this.toDoItems = ko.observableArray([
        new ToDo("Watch Person of Interest"),
        new ToDo("Study for Midterm exam"),
        new ToDo("Buy groceries for Luis")
    ]);

    this.addToDoItem = function() {
        this.toDoItems.push(new ToDo($('.txt').val()));
        $('.txt').val('');
    }

    this.removeToDoItem = function(item) { 
        this.toDoItems.remove(item); 
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ToDoViewModel());
```

Here is the markup inside a 'body' tag:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>ToDo List</td>
</tr>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: toDoItems">
    <tr>
        <td><label data-bind="text: toDoItem"></label></td>            
        <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeToDoItem">Remove</a></td>
    </tr>    
</tbody>
</table>

<input class="txt"/>
<button data-bind="click: addToDoItem">Add Item</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scope is your problem. The error you should be seeing is:

> TypeError: this.toDoItems is undefined

(Or something similar) Which essentially means that `this` isn't within the `ToDoViewModel` scope but within the click event scope so `this` is a different object reference (and therefor doesn't have a `removeToDoItem` method).

However if you store the reference (like many examples using `var self = this`) you can then reference `self.toDoItems` later and the list will be located. Basically:

```
function ToDoViewModel(){
  var self = this; // add this line

  //...

  self.removeToDoItem = function(item){
    // now keep referencing `self`
    self.toDoItems.remove(item);
  }
}
```

You can probably change all reference of `this.` to `self.` (as long as it's referencing objects within the ViewModel's direct scope).

Updated example can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/aLV7p/).

Answer (score 1):

In the "removeToDoItem" function "this" does not mean what you think it does.

The solution is to define a private variable inside the ToDoViewModel and assign it to this.

```
function ToDoViewModel() {
var that=this;
```

then inside removeToDoItem you can refer to it.

```
this.removeToDoItem = function(item) { 
    that.toDoItems.remove(item); 
}
```